# I am calling the sql statement with a php loop and I want to change it to be called only once

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am a novice developer running a server.

Recently, I am running a server using php and mysql.

However, the server keeps hitting and checking, and mysql is eating all the cpu.

I think it is a problem to put the sql query in the loop statement because of poor skill.

I looked around, but it couldn't be solved, but I saw a post that told me to solve it with a join statement rather than repeatedly calling the sql statement.

If you think about it, it is definitely a problem by repeatedly calling the sql statement, so I think it will improve if it can be processed as a single query.

But I don't know how to change it right now...

I am using a code similar to the one below, not the code that is actually used. Please help me on how to change this.

It's a little embarrassing to use this code...

I want to print the sum.

I have 24 hours worth of data.
This code takes the number of records in 1 minute and adds up the value divided by 100.

```
$sum = 0;
for ($i = 0; $i < 1440; $i++){
    $time1 = date("Y/m/d H:i",(strtotime($basetime) - 72000 + ($i * 60))).":00";
    $time2 = date("Y/m/d H:i",(strtotime($basetime) - 60 + ($i * 60))).":59";
    $sql = "select count(*) as cnt from mytable where start_time between '$time1' and '$time2'";
    $query_result = mysqli_query($sql);
    $sum += 100 / $query_result['cnt']);
}
echo $sum;
```

Comment: Add information (in words, not in code) to your question about the purpose of the code. What are your trying to achieve ?

Comment: Are you only interested in the total result of `$sum` or are you also interested in the value of every individual row?

Comment: the sum of all counts are just the counts of all records, so one query is already enough

Comment: i interested in the value of every individual row

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql = "select count(*) as cnt from mining where start_time between '$time1' and '$time2'";
 $query_result = sql_fetch($sql);
$sum = 0;
for ($i = 0; $i < 1440; $i++){
    $time1 = date("Y/m/d H:i",(strtotime($basetime) - 72000 + ($i * 60))).":00";
    $time2 = date("Y/m/d H:i",(strtotime($basetime) - 60 + ($i * 60))).":59";
    $sum += $query_result['cnt']);
}
```